# How can we get 2 UUID for Same device for same iOS App without Delete or Re-Install the same App?

Tags: ios, swift, uuid

We have observed the wired observation. We are generating UUID from below API

```
guard let identifierForVendor = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor else { return "" }
```

after generating we are storing in Keychain and Coredata while retrieving the UUID 2nd time we are getting from coredata. for few scenarion we have observed that 2 different UUID for the same Device. Can any one have face this issue or observed such kind of behaviour in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, UUID can change. If the user deletes the app and all other apps created by the app vendor in that case the identifierForVendor can change.
In one other case it can change is if it was not installed from the App Store and then later is. For example, you give the client an ad-hoc build to test and then later they install the app from the App Store

Comment: none of any thing happened in my case(Not deleted, only downloaded from AppStore only) but still i see the same behaviour.

Comment: you are getting different UUID at the time of app launch ?

Comment: Yes not for all users but we got the case for specific 4-5 users

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor)

> ... The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode ...

I am not sure how you detect or "debug" that the value has changed, but if you run the app multiple times through Xcode I assume this is what could differ from your previous persisted value.

As a last statement in the same documentation Apple states

> Therefore, if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.

Comment: We are using Monitoring tools Kibana and Quantummetric. There we could clearly see the same device but different UUID

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. One additional question - if you are getting different UUIDs, how do you detect/know it is the same device and uniquely identify it?

Comment: from the Kibana We see the same userId and device model but 2 different sessions of UUID

Comment: This seems quite strange. Could it be that some users of yours have more than 1 device? Also you said it cannot be a reinstall, but this still seems like the most obvious answer to me aside from user having more than one device.

Comment: The user might have more than 1 device but both device has different device model in our case everything is same other than UUID.